# Why does Python's multiprocessing Queue have a buffer and a Pipe

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, multiprocessing

**Context**

I have been looking at the source code  [SEE HERE](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/python/pypy/lib-python/2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py) for multiprocessing Queue `Python 2.7` and have some questions.

- A deque is used for a buffer and any items put on the Queue are appended to the deque but for get(), a pipe is used.
- We can see that during put, if the feeder thread has not been started yet it will start.
- The thread will pop objects off the thread and send them on the read side of the above pipe.

**Questions**

- So, why use a deque and a pipe?
- Couldn't one just use a deque (or any other data structure with FIFO behavior) and synchronize push and pop?
- Likewise couldn't one also just use a Pipe, wrapping send and recv?

Maybe there is something here that I am missing but the feeder thread popping items and putting them on the Pipe seems like overkill.

Answer (score 5):

The `multiprocessing.Queue` is a port of the standard `Queue` capable of running on multiple processes. Therefore it tries to reproduce the same behaviour.

A `deque` is a list with fast insertion/extraction on both sides with, theoretically, infinite size. It's very well suited for representing a stack or a queue. It does not work across different processes though.

A `Pipe` works more like a socket and allows to transfer data across processes. Pipes are Operating System objects and their implementation differs from OS to OS. Moreover, **pipes have a limited size**. If you fill a pipe your next call to `send` will block until the other side of it does not get drained.

If you want to expose a `Queue` capable to work across multiple processes in a similar fashion than the standard one, you need the following features.

- A buffer capable of storing messages in arrival order which have not been consumed yet.
- A channel capable of transferring such messages across different processes.
- Atomic `put` and `get` methods able to leave the control to the User on when to block the program flow.

The use of a `deque` a `Thread` and a `Pipe` is one of the simplest way to deliver these features but it's not the only one.

I personally prefer the use of bare pipes to let processes communicate as it gives me more control on my application.

Answer (score 0):

A dequeue can only be in one process memory so using it to pass data between processes is impossible(...*)

You could use just a `Pipe` but then you would need to protect it with locks, and I guess this is why a dequeue was introduced.